# Forcing Voiceover to read particular word (homographs)

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I want to use the word "live" (l-eye-v) for an event on now rather than "live" (l-i-v) as in "will she live". Is there any way to force this?

The answers to [VoiceOver accessibility label for Touch ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133503/voiceover-accessibility-label-for-touch-id) are fairly relevant to this question and suggest that the answer is no, there is nothing that can be done to force it. This question title is much more generally applicable and searchable so I think it is a useful addition even if answers do link there. There are also aspects of the linked question that are applicable only to a particular situation.

There is also [VoiceOver pronunciation issue: "Live" "ADD"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354498/voiceover-pronunciation-issue-live-add?rq=1) which discusses the specific case of "Live" too worth a read if you find this page now.

Comment: This has been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133503/voiceover-accessibility-label-for-touch-id/33134356

Answer (score 2):

A good way to implement this is to override the accessibilityLabel getter property.  This way you don't have to track both strings separately, just have a dictionary of words that need phonetic replacement.  So for example, if your object were a UILabel, you could do something like this:

```
-(NSString*)accessibilityLabel {
    NSMutableString* mutableResult = [NSMutableString new];

    for (NSString* word in [self.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \t\n"]]) {
        if ([word isInDictionary]) {
            [mutableResult appendFormat:@" %@", [word phoneticReplacement]];
        } else {
            [mutableResult appendFormat:@" %@", word];
        }
    }

    return mutableResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, what I usually do is just add a separate accessibility string (as opposed to using the text displayed to the user) that contains the word phonetically. So try something like lyve/lieve. Text to speech is a complicated process and requires a lot of AI to work properly with homonyms.