# VoiceOver pronunciation issue: "Live" "ADD"

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to implement accessibility for an iOS App and have been bumping into some of the nuances and quirks involved.

For example:
I have a label in my app that reads: "This is a live event."
The definition of live in this context is "something that is currently happening" and when pronounced it should rhyme with "Five".

However, voiceover understands and reads the word "live" as in: "live and let die", and is mispronounced rhyming the word with "Give".

Similarly, another issue I am bumping into is with the word "ADD" in the context of "ADD A SELECTION". The meaning of the word in its context is "to add something to a basket", but is being pronounced as "A.D.D. (Attention deficit disorder)"

Is there a programatic way to give context to words when enabling your app for accessibility?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but I would assume there is something similar to the `accessibilityLabel` where you can change the pronunciation of it somehow. Looking now. Possibly in the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` delegate?

Comment: It could be pronouncing A.D.D because the letters are in caps. You could apply `-capitalizedString` or `-lowecaseString` before handing over the string to speak.

Comment: Sorry, I got side tracked by "currently alive" and you said it should rhyme with "give"?  Perhaps that's an accent thing but I pronounce "this is a live event" and "currently alive" as both rhyming with "five".  The "give" version of "live" would be something like James Bond's "Live and Let Die".

In any event, screen reader users are used to mispronunciations.  It's great if you can fix it but unless you've already fixed other major accessibility issues, I wouldn't worry about it.  If you can get WCAG 2.1.1 and 4.1.2 squared away, you'll have a lot of your a11y work completed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using tips and tricks with capitals or doubled letters that currently work but **may be obsolete** in a future version of iOS or **inconvenient with braille**, I suggest to **use the `accessibilitySpeechIPANotation` key** inside an attributed string in order to define the appropriate phonetic sound *(available since iOS11)*: this method is proven and will last in time.

[Phonemes can be generated](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#speech-synthesis) thanks to your mobile device settings:

- iOS 13 +...: `Accessibility` - `VoiceOver` - `Speech` - `Pronunciations`.
- iOS 12: `General` - `Accessibility` - `Speech` - `Pronunciations`.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with this for a while but I found out a simple solution...
If you add another "L" letter to the "Live" string it will pronounce live as five.

Try this --> "Llive"

Comment: not working under iOS 13.2. It is pronounced like river without the last "r". → But maybe that's because my voiceOver is set to German (we are also doing stuff "live" and use that word in German sentences)

Answer (score 2):

The solution - at least for iOS 9.1 and newer - changing the capitalisation of the word also changes the pronunciation:

- Live rhymes with five
- live rhymes with give

Comment: Tested and this isn't true on iOS 12.4.

Comment: also not true under iOS 13.2

Answer (score 1):

They are two ways of bypassing a bug in a screenreader:

- ignoring it : it's a bug in the screenreader, not in your code
- using a different sentence.

For instance, you could say "this event is live" (if it works better, which i doubt), or "this event is on the air" (depending on the context of course, but you could fine a better alternative).

You might think about using `aria-label` (for web apps, or its equivalent `accessibilityLabel` in native application) to provide an audio alternative like "this is alive event" (because alive rhymes with five) for screenreaders but `aria-label` is also used by braille display, and **then this would be a quite bad idea.**

As someone said in the comments above, screenreaders users know perfectly well how their screenreader would badly pronounce some words.

EDIT: See [@Bugs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354498/voiceover-pronunciation-issue-live-add#answer-52348730) for a solution on native iOS apps (>=iOS11)

Comment: ARIA has no bearing on native apps.

Comment: @Aodh I clearly stated that `aria-label` was not an answer. This question is not intended to target specifically native iOs apps as there are also web and hybrid apps. If the author might be developping a native app (which I couldn't know from his own question), people finding this question will be happy to find differents answers for different kind of apps.

Comment: @Adam where do you clearly state that it's not the answer? The OP is asking about iOS apps specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `accessibilityLabel` for the label to pronounce the text how you want.

For the OPs example:

```
label1.accessibilityLabel = @"This is a liv event." //notice live is spelled liv so it is pronounced for the correct context
label2.accessibilityLabel = @"add a selection"
```

This can also be done via the storyboard/nib by selecting the label and view the "identity inspector"

[image: Identity inspector screen shot]

Comment: Note that accessibility label (=aria-label) might be used by braille displays.