# How to force screen-reader pronounciation?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I am building a website and I am attempting to make it as accessible as I can by the use of ARIA tags, role tags etc.

A navigation menu item is "Changing Lives". Where this is being read out by screen readers  as "Changing Lives" (as in "Gives" and not "Knives").

Another navigation menu item is "About Us" but it is being read out by screen readers as "About U.S.".

I'm looking for assistance in how to force pronounciations for screen readers.

Comment: Have you tried writing the actual text in HTML properly, like "About us"? One common mistake is also capital letters in HTML like "ADD" – _title case_ and _uppercase_ are stylistic, optical features, that should be applied by means of CSS: `text-transform: capitalize`

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it, there are many words that screen readers do this on.

The only way you can influence pronunciation (while adhering to best practices) is to set the HTML lang attribute (language) correctly.

With regards to your **About Us issue**, capitalisation plays a big part in pronunciation. If you have used upper case (either in CSS or in HTML) it may exhibit this behaviour.

Above all **do not resort to hacks such as double letters to fix this**.....fixing it in one screen reader will break it in 3 others....just follow best practices.

Comment: Worth mentioning that many/most screen readers have their speech handled by speech synthesizers which they do not themselves control. Users can use different speech synthesizers which make different guesses about how to announce something. I've seen "IV" announced as "Four" and "Roman Four" with the same screen reader, just by switching the screen reader's synth settings. (We wanted it to announce "Eye-Vee", because this was a medical setting).

Comment: Great tip! - never actually realised as I hardly change the synth voice!

Comment: +1 to the advice here. Also remember that some users use Braille, and any hacks used to make the text sound right - eg by using phonetic spellings - will break things for Braille users.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same problem as the user in the following question, and the same answer should apply:

[VoiceOver pronunciation issue: "Live" "ADD"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354498/voiceover-pronunciation-issue-live-add#answer-36391181)

- you can ignore it,
- you can use different words.