# Make UITextField with VoiceOver read numbers as digits

Tags: uitextfield, accessibility, voiceover

Our App has a few `UITextField` where users enter alphanumeric input codes such as "AA149873A".

We'd like voice over to read these as "A A 1 4 9 8 7 2 A", but it instead reads the digits as a number: "One hundred and forty nine thousand, eight hundred and seventy three".

Is there some way to configure `UITextField` so that it knows its content shouldn't be thought of as numbers, but individual digits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 13 it is possible to add a string attribute to direct voice-over vocalisation to spell strings out as individual letters and digits.

I've not found a way to direct `UITextField` to add this attribute to its content. However, a `UITextField` subclass can override it's `accessibilityValue` to achieve this.

The subclass given here adds a property to enable or disable this behaviour.

```
final class AccessibilityTextField: UITextField {

    var isAlphanumeric: Bool = false

    override public var accessibilityAttributedValue: NSAttributedString? {
        get {
            guard let text = text, !text.isEmpty else {
                return nil
            }

            return NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: valueAttributes)
        }

        set {
            // Ignore these values.
            _ = newValue
        }
    }

    private var valueAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] {
        guard #available(iOS 13.0, *), isAlphanumeric else {
            return [:]
        }

        return [.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut: true]
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is given in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562992/2547229) here that doesn't use the iOS 13 feature `. accessibilitySpeechSpellOut`. However, I've seen it suggested that this is not ideal for [brail output systems](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-accessibility-attributes-4aa120b3cc76) as they also use `accessibilityLabel`. Perhaps this is a good fallback on pre iOS 13 systems.

Answer (score 4):

> We'd like voice over to read these as "A A 1 4 9 8 7 2 A", but it instead reads the digits as a number: "One hundred and forty nine thousand, eight hundred and seventy three".

The fastest wy to reach your goal is to **add spaces between each character** in the `accessibilityValue` of the `UITextField` as follows:

```
class AccessibilityTextField: UITextField {

    var _str: String?
    override var text: String? {
        get { return _str}
        set {
            _str = newValue!
            accessibilityValue = _str!.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: " ")
        }
    }

    convenience init() { self.init() }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
}
```

I didn't implement all the text field delegate stuff to test it ⟹ I created a blank project only with an `UITextField` adding a *"BB0024FG"* plain text and changed the text in the `viewDidAppear` of my view controller:

```
myTextField.text = "AA14987A"
```

In the end, VoiceOver spells out each character after another without reading out the initial plain text.

Following this rationale, you have a way that let **VoiceOver know that the `UITextField` content must be thought as individual digits**.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't answer before. I came across this approach in another answer. It was pointed out there that while it works for voice over, `accessibilityLabel` is also used for brail output systems (! I had no idea), and on these, it's not ideal to have lots of extra spaces added. I think it works as a good alternative on pre iOS 13 systems where `. accessibilitySpeechSpellOut` is not available. Thank you.

Comment: I think [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33134356/2547229) was where I saw this.

Comment: Hi – Which answer do you think I should give the tick to? Yours is practical and works for all current iOS, but I think the one I've given is preferable for iOS 13 and on.

Comment: @Benjohn: yours is the best one because it takes into account the braille output systems that my solution sets aside unfortunately... my proposal is only a workaround.  